# What are the references for a content builder folder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

The below code works for interaction with Marketing Cloud classic content, I now need to adapt it for use with Content Builder but cannot find the right references, I assume 'ContentType' is 'Asset' but that's about as much as I know

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
%%[
Set @resultString = "Display name|File URL~"
Set @FolderDate = FormatDate(Now(),"yyyyMMdd") 
Set @FolderName = Concat("HOLSendDate",@FolderDate) 
SET @Retrieve = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest") 
SetObjectProperty(@Retrieve, "ObjectType", "DataFolder")
AddObjectArrayItem(@Retrieve,"Properties","ObjectID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@Retrieve, "Properties", "ID")

SET @CFP = CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart")

SET @SFP1 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@SFP1,"Property","ContentType")
SetObjectProperty(@SFP1,"SimpleOperator","equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@SFP1,"Value","media")

SET @SFP2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@SFP2,"Property","Name")
SetObjectProperty(@SFP2,"SimpleOperator","equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@SFP2,"Value",@FolderName)

SetObjectProperty(@CFP,"LeftOperand",@SFP1)
SetObjectProperty(@CFP,"RightOperand",@SFP2)
SetObjectProperty(@CFP,"LogicalOperator","AND")

SetObjectProperty(@Retrieve, "Filter", @CFP)
SET @FolderRetrieve = InvokeRetrieve(@Retrieve,@status_rr,@reqID)

IF RowCount(@FolderRetrieve) > 0 THEN
SET @ID = Field(row(@FolderRetrieve,1),"ID")
]%%

<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var CategoryID = Stringify(Variable.GetValue("@ID"));
Variable.SetValue("@CategoryID",CategoryID);
</script>

%%[
SET @Retrieve2 = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")    

SetObjectProperty(@Retrieve2, "ObjectType", "Portfolio")
AddObjectArrayItem(@Retrieve2,"Properties","DisplayName")
AddObjectArrayItem(@Retrieve2, "Properties", "CustomerKey")
AddObjectArrayItem(@Retrieve2, "Properties", "ThumbURL")
AddObjectArrayItem(@Retrieve2, "Properties", "FileURL")

SET @SFP = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@SFP,"Property","CategoryID")
SetObjectProperty(@SFP,"SimpleOperator","equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@SFP,"Value",@CategoryID)

SetObjectProperty(@Retrieve2, "Filter", @SFP)
SET @PortfolioRetrieve = InvokeRetrieve(@Retrieve2,@status_rr2,@reqID2)
If RowCount(@PortfolioRetrieve) > 0 Then
    for @i = 1 to RowCount(@PortfolioRetrieve) do
        SET @DisplayName = Field(Row(@PortfolioRetrieve,@i),"DisplayName")
        SET @FileURL = Field(Row(@PortfolioRetrieve,@i),"FileURL")
        Set @resultString = concat(@resultString,@DisplayName,"|",@FileURL,"~")
    next @i
EndIf       
EndIf
If @resultString == "Display name|File URL~" Then
Set @resultString = "Do not send"
EndIF
]%%
%%=v(@resultString)=%%
```